# Searching a Min Binary Heap

Tags: java, algorithm, logic, heap

I have to simply present an algorithm not in code, but in words to find the maximum value in a min binary heap. I argued that because a min binary heap contains the highest value at the bottom, if you begin your search at the end of the index rather than the beginning, you will find it right away rather than searching from the beginning. Does this make any sense in practice and theory? Thank you!

Comment: Bottom meaning highest index number. If the min heap contains 2 at index 0 and 100 at index 30. Then if you start your search at index 30, you will find the term faster than if starting at index 0.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a min binary heap:

```
        1
   2        5
3     4
```

Just pointing out that although the maximum is guaranteed to be a leaf, not all of the leaves have to be at the lowest level of the tree.

Answer (score 0):

The binary heap contains ~`n/2` leaves, where `n` is the total number of elements in the heap, and indeed one of them will be the max value.

However, you have to traverse over all of them to find the maximal value, so the speedup you recieve is only *2, and using this approach is still `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a min-binary-heap:

```
        1
    2       3
 10    5  20    7
```

The "maximum" can be **anywhere** in the leaves.

> if you begin your search at the end of the index rather than the
>   beginning, you will find it right away rather than searching from the
>   beginning.

That's incorrect.

It is possible to skip the non-leaves, but that does not really help in asymptotic complexity because a heap with `n` elements, have approximately `n/2` leaves. A simple linear scan is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

A binary heap's structure is a balanced tree. Internally it can be presented as a tree of nodes or as an array.

If it is represented as a tree, you have no choice but to traverse all the nodes down to the leaves, which is an O(n) solution, unless you have references to the leaves.

If it is represented as an array you can do a little better. Note that the 2 children of element k are at 2k and 2k+1 respectively. That means you can look at the end of the array and walk backwards. This will be faster but will still be O(n)

Answer (score 0):

If the size of the heap is n, you need to search from index n-1 to (n-1)/2. The highest of these numbers will give you the max number.

Words wise, you have to search ALL LEAF NODES to find out the highest number. This is a O(n/2) or a O(n) operation.

Comment: I believe the range is `n-1` to `(n-1)/2`. Given an array-based heap of size `n`, a node at index `p` is a leaf node if `2*p+1 >= n`.  Solving for `p` gives `p = (n-1)/2`.